# Why the following c function is same as the asm code

Tags: c, assembly

Can someone explain me why the following c code is equivalent to the asm code?

```
void arith1(){
    a=(b*10)+(5/(-e));
}
```

Why do we put the value of b in a ecx register.

ASM code:

```
mov  ecx, DWORD PTR _b
imul ecx, 10             ; $1 = b * 10
mov  esi, DWORD PTR _e  
neg  esi                 ; $2 = -e
mov  eax, 5
cdq
idiv esi                 ; $3 = 5 / -e
add  ecx, eax            ; $4 = $1 + $3
mov  DWORD PTR _a, ecx   ; a = $4
```

Comment: It isn't, it's equivalent to `(b * 10) + (5 / -e)`

Comment: Is the C code supposed to have a divide in it? Or is that the basis for the question?

Comment: Almost any other register could be used too. esi, edi, edx, ebp would work, so just one register is chosen.

Comment: Surely not edx, seeing as there is a cdq in there.. and an idiv.

Comment: You are really asking two questions here. The answer to the first one is: it isn't, while the second one would be: why not? Also, it's **the** ecx register, not **a** ecx register. The processor only has one register named thusly.

Comment: @harold, yes it's a divide, i miss copied.

Comment: Is the C code actually correct? There's a closing parenthesis missing.

Comment: Each c/c++ code is translated to assembly language eventually. Why is this surprising you? Get a i386 assembly reference and read it.

Answer (score 3):

```
mov  ecx, DWORD PTR _b
imul ecx, 10             ; edx:eax = b * 10
mov  esi, DWORD PTR _e  
neg  esi                 ; esi = -e
mov  eax, 5
cdq                      ; edx:eax = 5
idiv esi                 ; eax = 5 / -e
add  ecx, eax            ; ecx = b * 10 + 5 / -e
mov  DWORD PTR _a, ecx   ; store result to a
```

The only non-intuitive part is that the imul and idiv instructions combine the edx and eax registers to form a 64-bit value.  The upper 32-bits are discarded after the imul instruction, C doesn't perform overflow checks.  The cdq instruction (convert double to quad) is required to turn the 32-bit value into a 64-bit value before dividing.

Comment: The double-width multiply is the single-operand form, not this one. This form (imul r,imm) is not even in the Intel manual, but is short for imul r,r,imm where both r's are the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
mov  ecx, DWORD PTR _b
```

Move the variable b into ecx register

```
imul     ecx, 10    ; $1 = b * 10
```

Multiply the ecx register by 10. (b*10)

```
mov  esi, DWORD PTR _e
```

Move the variable e into the esi register.

```
neg  esi    ; $2 = -e
```

Negate the esi register. (-e)

```
mov  eax, 5
```

Move 5 into the eax register.

```
cdq
```

Convert eax into a quad-word (I think, not sure what it's needed for).

```
idiv     esi    ; $3 = 5 / -e
```

Divide eax by esi (5 / -e)

```
add  ecx, eax   ; $4 = $1 + $3
```

Add eax to ecx (b*10)**+**(5/-e).

```
mov  DWORD PTR _a, ecx  ; a = $4
```

Move ecx into variable a (a **=** (b*10)+(5/-e)).

Comment: cdq is needed because there may be any old junk in edx which is used in the idiv. xor edx,edx would work just as well in this case (5 is definitely positive)